# Multiply two arrays with different length in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multiplication

I have a dynamic array:

```
$variants = [
    'color' => ['Blue', 'Red', 'Pink'],
    'size' => ['X', 'S'],
    ... (maybe more elements like above or not)
];
```

I expect this:

```
$result = [
    0 => ['color' => 'Blue', 'size' => 'X'],
    1 => ['color' => 'Blue', 'size' => 'S'],
    2 => ['color' => 'Red', 'size' => 'X'],
    3 => ['color' => 'Red', 'size' => 'S'],
    4 => ['color' => 'Pink', 'size' => 'X'],
    5 => ['color' => 'Pink', 'size' => 'S']
];
```

Result is the multiplying of all array lengths. I've searched but not found the solution yet. Hope anyone could help. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried to make a nested loop through all inside array. But with dynamic array length, I've not found the solution yet!

Comment: Then please show us the code you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, you need a preparation and an aggregation step for this. But it is possible without falling back to recursion:

```
<?php
$variants = [
    'color' => ['Blue', 'Red', 'Pink'],
    'size' => ['X', 'S'],
    'weight' => [150, 250]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($variants as $key => $set) {
    foreach ($set as $entry) {
        $result[] = [$key => $entry];
    }
    break;
}
array_shift($variants);

foreach($variants as $setKey => $set) {
    $buffer = $result;
    $result = [];

    foreach ($set as $entry) {

        foreach ($buffer as $buf) {
            $result[] = array_merge($buf, [$setKey => $entry]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

The output of that is:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "X"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "X"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Pink"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "X"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Pink"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "X"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(250)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "X"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(250)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Pink"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "X"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(250)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(250)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(250)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Pink"
    ["size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["weight"]=>
    int(250)
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for complex array as-is, but can be adapted. If the input array is of the form array('color'=>array(array('id'=>123, 'name'=>'blue', 'texture'=>'rough'), array('id'=>456, 'name'=>'red', 'texture'=>'smooth'), ...), ...);

You will lose the key-value pairs, but can get them back from the inner array.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. This wasn't requested on this question here, so by the OP here, which is why it is not implemented in this answer. It certainly is correct that you can adapt it to more complex situations.

Answer (score 0):

A function that makes what you want

```
function get_combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($property => $property_value));
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}

$variants = [
    'color' => ['Blue', 'Red', 'Pink'],
    'size' => ['X', 'S']
];

$result = get_combinations($variants);
```

The result will be like you want it.

Comment: It uses less foreach loops than the accepted answer. More or less is the same.

Comment: Yeah, because he comes first and it works :(. Anyway, many thanks for your short and nice function!